# Drag and drop animation software similar to Muvizu

Tags: osx, gratis, animation

I am looking for a drag and drop animation software for Mac. I did a little research and found [Muvizu](http://www.muvizu.com/What-is-Muvizu) which I loved but it seems to be only for Windows.

Here are the requirements the software needs:

1. Drag and drop
2. Simple to learn
3. For Mac OS
4. Has a free version
5. I want the software to be able to animate people: Moving, talking, waving, etc.
6. Online tools are OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an application by MIT called [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/), which works by dragging and dropping commands into a script which can make the program move sprites (characters and objects), preform calculations, and change appearance.

You add a sprite to a project, drag together a series of blocks like so

[image]

to create a loop for a specific sprite. You can also set a background (and change the background) to animate.

[image]

and create something like this

(Image taken from MIT's [excellent video tutorials](http://info.scratch.mit.edu/Video_Tutorials))

You can [download it here](http://scratch.mit.edu/scratch_1.4/) or try out the web based version (and explore example scripts) at [the scratch website](http://scratch.mit.edu/).

The only way to export a Scratch program is to upload it to the Scratch website, where other users can use the program in a Java interface or can download it to their own computers.

Comment: How Scratch meets OP requirements?

Comment: Having used Scratch, I can say it certainly does, although it's not exactly an intuitive choice as a quasi-programming environment.  But consider it's designed to be used by elementary school students.  I can't remember if there is an OSX native version but the web version is fine.

Comment: the scratch program is mainly for elementary students. I konow this because I used when i was in third grade ( I'm still in elementary school)